# Suspected exploit log_rotari2

Tags: malware

Recently performance of my Ubuntu 18 server heavily degraded. I found in process list the following process, which consumes all CPU of my server.

> ./log_rotari2 --coin monero -o suxsuxsux.com:3333 -u linux -p linux
> --nicehash --donate-level=1 --cpu-priority=5 --cpu-no-yield -k -B

Maybe somebody knows what it is and how to remove this process? Sorry my knowlege of Ubuntu is very limited. Thank you.

Update: System is Ubuntu Linux 18.04.5, Linux 4.15.0-156-generic on x86_64

Following valuable comments, I found this extra info about this process.

```
Current dir Directory   4096    2   /  
Root dir    Directory   4096    2   / 
Program code    Regular file    6289312 19267940    /tmp/xmrig-6.14.1/log_rotari2 (deleted) 
2u  Regular file    1807    19141142    /tmp/#19141142 (deleted)
```

It seems that the process has been created and then its executable was deleted from the disk. I cannot even find executable file.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  No such release, so do you mean it's a Ubuntu Core 18 server product?  Ubuntu products using the *year* format are different to the more common *year.month* format products.

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/redis-alpine-malware/105143 https://blog.aquasec.com/container-attacks-on-redis-servers

Comment: There is only one correct answer: reinstall from a clean installation medium. Removing the thread is not a solution. Your admin account should be considered exposed and there could be a script on your system buried into another script that is waiting for you to remove it :)

Comment: It looks like some kind of cryptocurrency mining bot, but is difficult to assess without more details. If you know the `pid` of the process (e.g. from the `top` command), you can find the path to the executable by running `sudo ls -l /proc/xxxxxx/exe` where `xxxxxx` is the `pid` of the process. You should then be able to remove the executable. (*Nonetheless* I agree with @Rinzwind and I would recommend a clean install.)

Comment: @Alejandro it looks like a miner indeed but the 2 links use the same `log_rotari2` for executing a ddos :) And that leads me to believe is it more than a miner